# Is there a way to import a .bw2package into Brightway2.5?

Tags: brightway

I am having issues finding a way to import a .bw2Package into bw25. bw2 activity browser results in a lot of issues, namely not being able to import ecoinvent successfully. Error message being "Exchange between (biosphere 3) and (ecoinvent) is invalid - one of these objects is unknown (i.e. doesn't exist as a process dataset). I have tried this on multiple computers and the error is the same.

I am trying to import a .bw2package into Brightway25 through jupyter notebook, but the following code resulted in an error where it would not finish the kernel process, or if it did eventually finish (30 minutes later), there would be no new database added using `bd.databases` command.

```
ei_importer = BW2Package.import_file(ei_path)
```

I tried looking through the documentation but could not find anything about importing a type of file that isn't ecoinvent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because the class names and filepaths have changed, but these are hard-coded in the [`bw2package` format](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/main/bw2io/package.py#L32).

Alternatives include using the project backup and restore functionality, exporting the LCI database to Excel and then restoring it, or re-running the reproducible data pipeline (you do have a reproducible data pipeline, right?) in the 2.5 installation.

Comment: My issue is that I cannot import a .bw2package into activity browser (brightway2) or into bw25, so my current .bw2package file is unusable. I am trying to learn bw25 so the exact database does not matter, but I am unable to import a database that isn't ecoinvent. Could you help lead me in the right direction for importing non ecoinvent databases?